# Predefined group in Prometheus alerts

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have the following query as part of my prometheus alerting rules in my rules.yml:

```
...
- alert: Test1
  expr: time() - camel_route_last_exchange_completed_timestamp{route="route1|route2|route3...|routex"}
  for: 10s
...
```

In short: I am looking for the time since the last time stamp **for certain routes**.

However, for means of clarity, I would prefer to leave out the specific routes and refer to a predefined group
*(e.g. route_group_A = "route1|route2|route3...|routex"})*
so that the query is readable:

`time() - camel_route_last_exchange_completed_timestamp{route="route_group_A "}`

Is this possible? If so, how and in which document to define this?

Thanks in advance!